# Can I install use Jedi with Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, jedi

I want install Jedi to run with XE4 Version of Delphi (Embarcadero), but don't exits a official version for do this.

Can I install a modified version to run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JEDI project is hosted on github. You can pull the latest source, which has support for XE4, from there: https://github.com/project-jedi

As a general rule, you should get into the habit of using the appropriate VCS repository whenever you want to obtain open source software. That will always have the latest version.